# Writing data to file adds ^M at end of line

Tags: php, linux, vim, fwrite

Using PHP i'm writing content to a `.htaccess` file using `fwrite`, this all works correctly but when i view the `.htaccess` in Vim afterwards it displays ^M at the end of each line that has been added. This doesn't seem to cause any issues but i'm unsure quite whats happening to cause this and whether it can be prevented?

this is the PHP:

```
    $replaceWith = "#SO redirect_301\n".trim($_POST['redirect_301'])."\n#EO redirect_301";
    $filename = SITE_ROOT.'/public_html/.htaccess';
    $handle = fopen($filename,'r');
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    if (preg_match('/#SO redirect_301(.*?)#EO redirect_301/si', $contents, $regs)){
    $result = $regs[0];
    }
    $newcontents = str_replace($result,$replaceWith,$contents);
    $filename = SITE_ROOT.'/public_html/.htaccess';
    $handle = fopen($filename,'w');
    if (fwrite($handle, $newcontents) === FALSE) {
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

When i check in Vim afterwards i will see something like this:

```
#SO redirect_301
Redirect 301 /from1 http://www.domain.com/to1^M
Redirect 301 /from2 http://www.domain.com/to2^M
Redirect 301 /from3 http://www.domain.com/to3
#EO redirect_301
```

The server is running CentOS and i'm working locally on a Mac

Comment: str_replace("\r","",$_POST['redirect_301']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your newlines are incoming as `\r\n`, not as `\n`.

Before writing to the file, you should replace the invalid input:

```
$input = trim($_POST['redirect_301']);
$input = preg_replace('/\r\n/', "\n", $input);    // DOS style newlines
$input = preg_replace('/\r/', "\n", $input);      // Mac newlines for nostalgia
```

Comment: OS X uses `\n` like any other UNIX, it was OS 9 and earlier that used `\r`

Comment: The ^M is an extra carriage return.

Comment: $input = preg_replace('/\r\n?/', "\n", $input);

Comment: @igorw it would be overkill too. just replace \r. However, your code is way more sensible than in the answer